# How do I get correct ajax url for backend?

Tags: backend, url

I am trying to make an ajax call to reload the information on the category edit page.

I know the url I am trying to create is `catalog_category/edit`, but `$this->getUrl('catalog_category/edit')` returns `catalog_category/index`.

Why is it returning index instead of edit? How do I get the correct url for ajax calls? Or do I need to manually specify the full url, in which case what is the best way to get the form key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL params should be in the form of route name (from config xpath) + controller path + action. Try

```
$this->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category/edit')
```

or

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category/edit')`
```